# Is this proof circular or is it valid?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof, fake-proofs

I am playing with the chernoff bounds and derived a bound from its additive version. The method I used seems a little suspicious and circular in logic, but I cant figure out what the mistake is.

**Additive form of Chernoff bound**

The following theorem is due to Wassily Hoeffding and hence is called the Chernoff-Hoeffding theorem.

**Chernoff-Hoeffding theorem**

Suppose $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are i.i.d. random variables, taking values in $\{0,1\}$. Let $p=\mathrm{E}\left[X_i\right]$ and $\delta>0$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \operatorname{Pr}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum X_i \geq p+\delta\right) \leq\left(\left(\frac{p}{p+\delta}\right)^{p+\delta}\left(\frac{1-p}{1-p-\delta}\right)^{1-p-\delta}\right)^n=e^{-D(p+\delta \| p) n} \\
& \operatorname{Pr}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum X_i \leq p-\delta\right) \leq\left(\left(\frac{p}{p-\delta}\right)^{p-\delta}\left(\frac{1-p}{1-p+\delta}\right)^{1-p+\delta}\right)^n=e^{-D(p-\delta \| p) n}
\end{aligned}
$$
where
$$
D(x \| y)=x \ln \frac{x}{y}+(1-x) \ln \left(\frac{1-x}{1-y}\right)
$$
is the Kullback-Leibler divergence between Bernoulli distributed random variables with parameters $x$ and $y$ respectively.

**What if we dont know $\mathrm{E}\left[X_i\right]$?**

Let $$\mu=n p$$
$$X=\sum X_i$$
Then,
\begin{equation}
 \operatorname{Pr}\left(X \geq \mu+n\delta\right) \leq e^{-D(\frac{\mu}{n}+\delta \| \frac{\mu}{n}) n}\label{ub} \\ \end{equation}

Suppose  we fix the value of $\delta=\delta^{lb}$,then,

\begin{equation}
 \operatorname{Pr}\left(X \geq \mu+n\delta^{lb}\right) \leq f\left( \mu,\delta^{lb},n\right)=\epsilon^{lb},
    \label{ubmod}
\end{equation}
where $f\left( \mu,\delta,n\right)=e^{-D(\frac{\mu}{n}+\delta \| \frac{\mu}{n}) n}$.

Then the above equation implies $\operatorname{Pr}\left(X-n\delta^{lb} \geq \mu\right) \leq \epsilon^{lb} \implies $

\begin{equation}\operatorname{Pr}\left(X-n\delta^{lb} < \mu\right) > 1-\epsilon^{lb}.\label{ubfunc} \end{equation}

If $f\left( \mu,\delta^{lb},n\right)=\epsilon^{lb}\leq f\left( \left(X-n \delta^{lb}\right),\delta^{lb},n\right)=\epsilon'^{lb}$ when $X-n\delta^{lb} < \mu$, then  we have,
\begin{eqnarray}
    \operatorname{Pr}\left(X \geq \mu+n\delta^{lb}\right) &\leq& f\left( \mu,\delta^{lb},n\right),\nonumber\\
    &\leq& f\left( \left(X-n \delta^{lb}\right),\delta^{lb},n\right)\nonumber\\
    &\leq&\epsilon'^{lb}.
\end{eqnarray}
which holds with probability $>1-\epsilon^{lb}\geq1-\epsilon'^{lb}$.

Is this correct?

If not, is there a way to convert this into a legit one? I need to avoid using the expectation value of the random variable to calculate the bound.

EDIT

One could also restatwe the proof the following way,

If $f\left( \mu,\delta^{lb},n\right)=\epsilon^{lb}\leq f\left( \left(X-n \delta^{lb}\right),\delta^{lb},n\right)=\epsilon'^{lb}$ when $X-n\delta^{lb} < \mu$, then  we have,
\begin{eqnarray}
   \operatorname{Pr}\left(X-n\delta^{lb} < \mu\right) &>& 1- f\left( \mu,\delta^{lb},n\right),\nonumber\\
    &>& 1- f\left( \left(X-n \delta^{lb}\right),\delta^{lb},n\right)\nonumber\\
    &>& 1 - \epsilon'^{lb}.
\end{eqnarray}
which holds with probability $>1-\epsilon^{lb}\geq1-\epsilon'^{lb}$.